# testing swfitui body views

Tags: swift, unit-testing, swiftui

I would like to be able to write a unit test for a SwiftUI View.

I want to test the image and text. 
I have tried using the inspector but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Image("cat@2")
                .resizable()
            Text("Lily")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

            Text("A LIITEL GIRL")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)

            HStack {
                Text("Breed:")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 11.0)
                 Text("English short hair")
                 .font(.largeTitle)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Color:")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 11.0)
                Text("Tabby")
                 .font(.largeTitle)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Size:")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding(.horizontal, 11.0)

                Text("Lager")
                 .font(.largeTitle)

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean, that tried [ViewInspector for SwiftUI](https://github.com/nalexn/ViewInspector#viewinspector-for-swiftui)? [Here is the list of what you can test](https://github.com/nalexn/ViewInspector/blob/master/readiness.md) with this framework.

The other way is described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZZ0gCMhsUI).

I think one of these options should be useful.